# Installing numba on Amazon ec2 ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, numba, llvmlite

I would like to install the numba module onto an AWS ec2 ubuntu instance (the free tier one). Although other models seem to work, numba is having problems installing. I have pasted the error message below. I am pretty out of my league here so any help resolving this would be enormously appreciated.

```
      ubuntu@ip-172-31-21-188:~/panel_sim$ pip install numba
Collecting numba
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/f2/938d6b0e6b0be158d7beb7cc6067243783d219e8e0a7474bbe69d0fb5472/numba-0.47.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy (from numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/5f/47e578b3ae79e2624e205445ab77a1848acdaa2929a00eeef6b16eaaeb20/numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting setuptools (from numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/b7/182161210a13158cd3ccc41ee19aadef54496b74f2817cc147006ec932b4/setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting llvmlite>=0.31.0dev0 (from numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/cc/04526507e80d546be5688ce0246e40277b61e7949c3347c6609b6a4154cf/llvmlite-0.32.1.tar.gz
Collecting funcsigs; python_version < "3.3" (from numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/cb/f5be453359271714c01b9bd06126eaf2e368f1fddfff30818754b5ac2328/funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" (from numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/10/369f50bcd4621b263927b0a1519987a04383d4a98fb10438042ad410cf88/singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34; python_version < "3.4" (from numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/2c/a9386903ece2ea85e9807e0e062174dc26fdce8b05f216d00491be29fad5/enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from singledispatch; python_version < "3.4"->numba)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/ff/48bde5c0f013094d729fe4b0316ba2a24774b3ff1c52d924a8a4cb04078a/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for llvmlite ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpuSf3tUpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  /usr/bin/python /tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    File "/tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 122
      raise ValueError(msg.format(_ver_check_skip)) from e
                                                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  error: command '/usr/bin/python' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build llvmlite
Installing collected packages: numpy, setuptools, llvmlite, funcsigs, six, singledispatch, enum34, numba
  Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VwINe_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.32.1', 'full': 'aa11b129c0b55973067422397821ae6d44fa5e70'}
    running build_ext
    /usr/bin/python /tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
      File "/tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 122
        raise ValueError(msg.format(_ver_check_skip)) from e
                                                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    error: command '/usr/bin/python' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VwINe_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1Jivcg/llvmlite/
```

Answer (score 0):

[according to this information,](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/621#issuecomment-674866601)
you should upgrade pip via

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then try your command

```
pip install numba
```